# i18next typescript false warning on t function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next, .d.ts

I'm trying to make react-i18next work with typescript, but I'm having a typescript warning on my editor even when the code is working fine.

The error:

```
Argument of type '["button.add"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[key: TemplateStringsArray | "en:button.add" | (TemplateStringsArray | "en:button.add")[], options?: TOptionsBase & $Dictionary & InterpolationMap<...>] | [key: ...] | [key: ...]'.
```

For context I'm using React-i18next 13.5.0, I18next 23.7.6, Typescript 5.2.2

My `i18n.ts`:

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import en from "../locale/en.json";
import vi from "../locale/vi.json";

export const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
  },
  vi: {
    translation: vi,
  },
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: "en",
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

`i18n.d.ts`:

```js
import resources from "./i18n-resources";

declare module "i18next" {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: { en: (typeof resources)["en"] };
  }
}
```

`i18n-resources.ts`:

```js
import en from '../locale/en.json';
import vi from '../locale/vi.json';

const resources = {
  en,
  vi
} as const;

export default resources;
```

Simplified `en.json`:

```json
{
  "button": {
    "add": "Add"
  }
}
```

Simplified usage:

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Usage = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>{t("button.add")}</div>
  );
};
```

Edit: My work-around is to change my d.ts into

```js
import resources from "./i18n-resources";

declare module "i18next" {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: typeof resources["en"];
    nsSeparator: ".";
  }
}
```

But I really want to know why and how to fix this properly.